# How to add in a GUI?

Tags: c#, user-interface, methods, addition, windows-forms-designer

I'm barely learning how to do GUI. So, I am new to this stuff. I'm using windows form application in visual stuidos.

I need help with adding all three inputs that I have entered into the text boxes.

- Do I need to create another method? I created sum to add all variables and also used the click button to display sum.

side note - `MessageBox.Show(sum)` has a red line under it

This is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double principal;
    double rate;
    double terms;
    double sum;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void inputTextBoxPrincipal_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        principal = Convert.ToDouble(inputTextBoxPrincipal.Text);
    }

    private void inputTextBoxRate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rate = Convert.ToDouble(inputTextBoxRate.Text);
    }

    private void inputTextBoxTerms_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        terms = Convert.ToDouble(inputTextBoxTerms);
    }


    private double add()
    {
        sum = principal + rate + terms;
        return sum;
    }

    private void clickButtonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(sum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Red lines usually mean the IDE does not like it. You could compile the code anyway and look at the error messages/warnings to find out why. - I don't see where "add()" is called. So without "add()",  how can "sum" ever get the correct values?

Comment: Try to find a tutorial and/or a book to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the   `clickButtonEnter_Click` event as below.

```
  private void clickButtonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double sum = add();
            MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
        }
```

EDIT: Also you don't need those `TextChanged` events. Just following is fine.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double principal;
    double rate;
    double terms;
    double sum;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }    

    private double add()
    {
        principal = Convert.ToDouble(inputTextBoxPrincipal.Text);
        rate = Convert.ToDouble(inputTextBoxRate.Text);
        terms = Convert.ToDouble(inputTextBoxTerms);

        sum = principal + rate + terms;
        return sum;
    }

    private void clickButtonEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sum = add();
            MessageBox.Show(sum.ToString());
    }

}
```

Comment: There an error that said it cannot convert from double to string.

Comment: It works now. Thank you for helping and giving some advice.

Comment: @LebronJamess There is a tick you must add near my answer.